# How to get Intent filters using PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

Is there a way i can get intent filters supported by an app by using PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS option **since i can't find a method that returns packageinfo instance**?

```
 List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivityOptions(this.
getComponentName(),
            new Intent[]{intent1},intent2, 
PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS);

for( ResolveInfo lauchable : launchables){

   ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
   ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                    activity.name);
            IntentFilter filter = launchable.filter;

            PackageInfo info = launchable.//i can't find a method that return
//PackageInfo instance in this lauchable.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same but for what I found until now it's quite impossible retrieve a complete list of Intent Filters from an app installed on a device. In particular, the GET_INTENT_FILTERS seems to be buggy.
On this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3217) it is specified the situation about this option.